# Psalm: How to handle dedicated view files?

Tags: php, testing, model-view-controller, types, psalm-php

My set-up comprises a `lib` folder with classes and a `view` folder with PHP files, that produce output. The views are imported inside a `View` class similar to this:

```php
class View {

    public function render(string $basename, Array $params) : string {
        extract($params, EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID, 'v');
        ob_start();
        include sprintf('%s/views/%s.php', dirname(__DIR__), $basename);
        $out = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $out;
    }

}
```

I have basically two problems with Psalm in this situation:

1. For `View::render` it reports a `UnresolvableInclude`. I can even type the `$basename` with something like

   ```
    @param "view1"|"view2"|"about" $basename
   ```

   without effect. The unresolvable include remains.
2. The `extract()` puts the content of `$params` in the local scope, where the view files are included. This allows me to have

   ```
    <?=escape($foo)?>
   ```

   “tags” in my view files with `$params === ['foo' => 'bar']`. However, Psalm doesn’t catch up on this and reports a lot of `UndefinedGlobalVariable` problems.

**My question:** How can I tell psalm about the view files and the variables? Or alternatively, how can I re-structure this code so that psalm can test it for me?

Comment: Technically your view is just a method that takes a bunch of variables and returns a string. So why not make it actually a method like here https://psalm.dev/r/66898ee87f ?

Comment: Thank you for that idea! Yes, technically that would work for me. I hesitate a bit, because it seems like a lot of OOP boilerplate, when all I want is a bit of good old-fashioned tag-soup PHP and `include_once "partial/component.php";` in a somewhat controlled manner. I assume, Psalm is the wrong tool to check the views then? It works like a charm, though, checking the OOP part of my code. But maybe I try to use a skrewdriver to handle a nail...

Comment: Thinking a bit harder about that, maybe I can minimize the boilerplate with plain functions... something like `function part1(string $foo, int $bar) { ?> html ... <?php part2($bar) ?> ... html <?php }` might fit the bill, being minimally more complex than the plain files. Put together in a namespace, some autoloading, then that might be a nice “PHP as template engine”-like solution... I’ll have to play a bit with that. In the meantime: If you like, you could copy your comment into an answer, then I can at least upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a demo [TemlateChecker plugin](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/blob/master/examples/TemplateChecker.php) in Psalm's repo that seems to do something similar: it looks at the docblock in the view file for the tag like `@variablesfrom ClassName::method` and makes them available in the template file. Or just properties on `$this` variable from that method, not sure. It's also mentioned in Psalm docs: [Checking non-PHP files](https://psalm.dev/docs/running_psalm/checking_non_php_files/).

Alternatively, you could wrap your template into a minimal method/function as technically view is just a function that takes a bunch of variables and returns a string: https://psalm.dev/r/66898ee87f

```php
<?php class HomePageView {  // view starts here
    /** @param list<string> $sections */
    public function render(
        string $title,
        array $sections
    ): string { ob_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
       <title><?=$title?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php foreach ($sections as $section): ?>
        <section><?=$section?></section>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php return ob_get_contents(); }} // view ends here ?>
```

This way any tool that analyzes code (including Psalm, but not limited to) would be able to understand it.